# Stop running function when one variable gets to zero

Tags: python

Hope you can help me. Please see the code below. What I am trying to achieve is for code to stop when "x" or "y" gets to 0. At the moment, "x" gets to 0 first, but function_b() is still run after that. I would like that if "x" gets to 0, function_b() would not run afterwards. How do I do that?
Thank you

```
from random import randint

x = 10
y = 10


def roll_dice():
    random_dice = randint(1, 6)
    return random_dice


def function_a():
    global x
    while x > 0:
        dice = roll_dice()
      
        if dice >= 1:
            x -= 5
        else:
            print('Better luck next time')
            
        if x <= 0:
            break
        else:
            function_b()

def function_b():
    global y
    while y > 0:
        dice = roll_dice()
      
        if dice >= 1:
            y -= 5
        else:
            print('Better luck next time')
           
        if y <= 0:
            break
        else:
            function_a()


def turns():

    if x > 0:
        function_a()
    else:
        print('good game')
    
    if y > 0:
        function_b()
    else:
        print('good game')


turns()
```

Comment: print('Better luck next time') is useless, as you do randint between 1 and 6, so it cannot be below 1.

Comment: This is only a modification of the original bigger code. Sorry. Should have said that in the description.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made some adjustement on your code :

```
from random import randint

x = 10
y = 10


def roll_dice():
    random_dice = randint(1, 6)
    return random_dice


def function_a():
    global x
    while x > 0 and y != 0:
        dice = roll_dice()
      
        if dice >= 1:
            x -= 5
        else:
            print('Better luck next time')
            
        if x <= 0:
            break
        else:
            function_b()

def function_b():
    global y
    while y > 0 and x !=0:
        dice = roll_dice()
      
        if dice >= 1:
            y -= 5
        else:
            print('Better luck next time')
           
        if y <= 0:
            break
        else:
            function_a()


def turns():

    if x > 0:
        function_a()
    else:
        print('good game')
    
    if y > 0:
        function_b()
    else:
        print('good game')


turns()
```

Comment: In function a and b x is never 0 inside the while loop as it is while>0 , except when the while is finished. Therefore, it makes no sense to evaluate it inside the while and can be put at the end of the while